# How to fetch Query Target DE folder path using WS Proxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to fetch all the query details in a BU and able to fetch below details

```
Name, customerkey, targetupdatetype, createddate, modifieddate, categoryID, TargetDEname
```

**Currently Working code:**

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var cols = ["Name","CustomerKey","CategoryID","TargetUpdateType","CreatedDate","ModifiedDate","DataExtensionTarget.Name"];
    var data = prox.retrieve("QueryDefinition", cols);
    var fields = [];
    for (var i=0; i<data.Results.length; i++) {
        fields.push({
            name: data.Results[i].Name,
            customerkey: data.Results[i].CustomerKey,
            targetupdatetype: data.Results[i].TargetUpdateType,
            createddate: data.Results[i].CreatedDate,
            modifieddate: data.Results[i].ModifiedDate,
            categoryID: data.Results[i].CategoryID,
            Target: data.Results[i].DataExtensionTarget.Name
            });
    }
    var de = DataExtension.Init('B2CB596F-466B-400F-8684');
    var result = de.Rows.Add(fields);        
    Write("Result: " + result + " rows added");
</script>
```

Now challenging part is i want to fetch Target DE folder name! How can i do this? any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'd just need to do another retrieve of the [**DataExtension**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm) object using the `DataExtensionTarget.Name` in your filter.

The resulting `CategoryID` is the ID of the folder.  Once you have that, you can retrieve the [**DataFolder**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm) object with that ID.

If you want to get fancy, you can build something that traverses all of the parent folder Category IDs and builds the full path.

This is the kind of thing that gets SDKs written.